# Store JSON without brackets and quotes

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, email

So I have a Nodejs server and it receives a JSON object then puts it in a variable and emails that content out. Here is my code:

```js
app.post('/sendEmail', function(req, res) {
 var answers = req.body.answers;
 var str = JSON.stringify(answers, null, "\t"); // stringify with tabs inserted at each level
 console.log(answers);
 var fromEmail = new helper.Email('ahun...ok.com');
 var toEmail = new helper.Email('ahun...ok.com');
 var subject = 'Survey Completion';
 var content = new helper.Content('text/plain', str);
 
 
 var mail = new helper.Mail(fromEmail, subject, toEmail, content);

 var sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
 var request = sg.emptyRequest({
   method: 'POST',
   path: '/v3/mail/send',
   body: mail.toJSON()
 });
 
 sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
   if (error) {
     console.log('Error response received');
   }
 });
 
 res.send("Success");
 
});
```

As you can see, I am using stringify to make the JSON more pretty, but it still has all the gross brackets and quotes and spacing as JSON. Is there a way to store the JSON in a more readable form?

The email content is here:
`var content = new helper.Content('text/plain', str);`
So the readable JSON needs to be stored in a variable with formatting and such.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: here is the JSON object being sent over:

```html
{

"question1": {
 "Reliable": true,
 "Knowledgeable": true,
 "Helpful": true,
 "Courteous": true
},
"question2": {
 "checked": "Extremely Well"
},
"question3": {
 "checked": "Extremely Well"
},
"question4": {
 "checked": 3
},
"fullName": "Test",
"address": "Test",
"city": "Test",
"state": "Test",
"zip": "321",
"areaCode": "321",
"phone": 1234567896,
"call": true,
"lifeInsurance": "Yes",
"brokerage": "Yes",
"bankName": "Regions"
}
```

Using the above JSON object, I would like to format it to be like so:

Question 1: Reliable, Knowledgable, Helpful, Courteous.

Question 2: Extremely Well.

Question 3: Extremely Well.

Question 4: 3.

Full Name: Test.

Address: Test.

....

Brokerage: Yes.

Bank Name: Regions.

Comment: well ... what would you like to send instead?

Comment: Id like to send the JSON object, but not making it look like the above object. I am trying to format it so it looks like it is just typed into an email.

Comment: Is this even possible?

Comment: can you perhaps show, **in the question** what you want your output format to be - saying what you don't want it to look like is not helpful - and yes, of course it's possible

Comment: I added an example of the output format. Sorry, I tried to be as clear as possible. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/hnfpj7yx/ (check the browser developer tools console)

Comment: That formatting is perfect. I would have never gotten that. I just tested it and I get an error at the second Object.keys, the error is: `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` This is being used on Nodejs. Thanks for the help

Comment: something in your data isn't as it appears then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data just needs a bit of massaging

```js
var data = {
    "question1": {
        "Reliable": true,
        "Knowledgeable": false,
        "Helpful": true,
        "Courteous": true
    },
    "question2": {
        "checked": "Extremely Well"
    },
    "question3": {
        "checked": "Extremely Well"
    },
    "question4": {
        "checked": 3
    },
    "fullName": "Test",
    "address": "Test",
    "city": "Test",
    "state": "Test",
    "zip": "321",
    "areaCode": "321",
    "phone": 1234567896,
    "call": true,
    "lifeInsurance": "Yes",
    "brokerage": "Yes",
    "bankName": "Regions"
};

var result = Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
    key = key.replace(/([A-Z]|\d+)/g, ' $1').replace(/^(.)/, (unused, p1) => p1.toUpperCase());
    if (!['string', 'number', 'boolean'].includes(typeof value)) {
        value = Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => (typeof value == 'boolean') ? (value ? key : undefined) : value).filter(v => v !== undefined).join(',');
    }
    result.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
    return result;
}, []);
console.log(result.join('\n'));
```

Note: I changed one of the true to false to check the logic

Tested in node 8.1.2

Comment: thanks for the code. It is what I have been looking for. But I have an issue with mine. Could you please help me as you're the author of this code? Please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120590/nested-objects-key-is-missing-after-it-is-formatted-and-rendered

Answer (score 0):

An even easier answer might be parsing the JSON then dumping it as YAML:

```
---
question1:
  Reliable: true
  Knowledgeable: true
  Helpful: true
  Courteous: true
question2:
  checked: Extremely Well
question3:
  checked: Extremely Well
question4:
  checked: 3
fullName: Test
address: Test
city: Test
state: Test
zip: '321'
areaCode: '321'
phone: 1234567896
call: true
lifeInsurance: 'Yes'
brokerage: 'Yes'
bankName: Regions
```

There are several YAML libraries for Node.js, and I don't remember which I like, but I want to say I have had pretty good luck with [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml).