# Nested objects' key is missing after it is formatted and rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ejs

I have this object which I have been trying to print in my ejs template without object syntaxes. I followed an answer here in StackOverflow and was successful in printing it without the syntaxes but it doesn't print everything in the nested object. What I mean is there are two nested objects in data(f and g). So the properties(keys) in those nested objects like name, email, phone, country, car are missing from the output. How can I also render that with their respected values?

Here's the object and the code which I used to format it:

```
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    try{
        let data = { 
                a: 'Tesla',
                b: 'Mclaren',
                c: 'Ferrari',
                d: 'Lamborghini',
                e: 'Lotus',
                'f':{ 
                    name: 'John',
                    'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
                    phone: '+12345678',
                    country: 'USA',
                    car: 'Toyota Prius' 
                },
                'g':{ 
                    name: 'Sophie',
                    'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
                    phone: '+12345678',
                    country: 'UK',
                    car: 'Nissan Bluebird' 
                },
                h: 'Volkswagen',
                i: 'Bugatti',
                j:[ 
                    '% mileage',
                    '% top speed',
                    '% suspension',
                    '% navigation',
                    '% horsepower',
                    '% 0-60s' 
                ] 
            }
            var result = Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
                key = key.replace(/([A-Z]|\d+)/g, ' $1').replace(/^(.)/, (unused, p1) => p1.toUpperCase());
                if (!['string', 'number', 'boolean'].includes(typeof value)) {
                    value = Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => (typeof value == 'boolean') ? (value ? key : undefined) : value).filter(v => v !== undefined).join(',');
                }
                result.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
                return result;
            }, []);
            var finalData = result.join('\n');
            res.render("data", {data: finalData});
    }catch(e){
        req.flash("error", "Unable to retrieve data. Please try again!");
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});
```

This is the result if I print it in the console:

```
A: Tesla
B: Mclaren
C: Ferrari
D: Lamborghini
E: Lotus
F: John,xyz@example.com,+12345678,USA,Toyota Prius
G: Sophie,xyz@example.com,+12345678,UK,Nissan Bluebird
H: Volkswagen
I: Bugatti
J: % mileage,% top speed,% suspension,% navigation,% horsepower,% 0-60s
```

This is the result after I render it in my ejs template:

```
A: Tesla B: Mclaren C: Ferrari D: Lamborghini E: Lotus F: John,xyz@example.com,+12345678,USA,Toyota Prius G: Sophie,xyz@example.com,+12345678,UK,Nissan Bluebird H: Volkswagen I: Bugatti J: % mileage,% top speed,% suspension,% navigation,% horsepower,% 0-60s
```

Expected result:

```
A: Tesla
B: Mclaren
C: Ferrari
D: Lamborghini
E: Lotus
F: 
Name: John
Email: xyz@example.com
Phone: +12345678
Country: USA 
Car: Toyota Prius
G: 
Name: Sophie
Email: xyz@example.com
Phone: +12345678
Country: UK
Car: Nissan Bluebird
H: Volkswagen
I: Bugatti
J: 
% mileage
% top speed
% suspension
% navigation
% horsepower
% 0-60s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty but should do the thing:

```
var result = Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
   key = key.toUpperCase();
   if (typeof value === 'object') {
     result.push(`${key}:`);
     if (Array.isArray(value)) {
       value.forEach(item => result.push(item));
     } else {
       Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
         key = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)
         result.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
       })
    } 
  } else {
    result.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
  return result;
}, []);
var finalResult = result.join("\n");
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for helping me out. I tried your code and I could render it in my template but there's a slight issue. After rendering it on my template, all the items are wrapped in a couple of lines. Is there any way I could render each item on a new line?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer to include 1 more line of code (for joining the array to a string), hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried that already. The items are in new line in the terminal but not in the webpage. May be something need to be done in the frontend?

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid I'm not familiar with EJS. Is this any help? https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/187 You might need to join the result array with `"<br>"` or something instead and then render the text as HTML.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I was rendering all the items in the array as simple texts. So they were wrapped in a single line. So i tried a loop in the template and used ```<li>``` for each item. And they are displayed in a list. I should thank you for the code. It's perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey mate, if you don't mind, I needed another help. Is it possible to get the same result but with good alignment? What I mean to say is I want all the colons to align perfectly. As key and value are 1 item in the array, I can't design the look of it from the frontend. So I was thinking if it's possible with js. It'd be a big help mate. If you want I can create another question here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure - right now you have an array of strings, and what you need is an array of objects. So replace the `result.push(...)` with something like `result.push({ key, value })` and then you can handle the key and value separately in the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer use `join` to get the proper expected result.

```
let data = { 
                a: 'Tesla',
                b: 'Mclaren',
                c: 'Ferrari',
                d: 'Lamborghini',
                e: 'Lotus',
                'f':{ 
                    name: 'John',
                    'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
                    phone: '+12345678',
                    country: 'USA',
                    car: 'Toyota Prius' 
                },
                'g':{ 
                    name: 'Sophie',
                    'e-mail': 'xyz@example.com',
                    phone: '+12345678',
                    country: 'UK',
                    car: 'Nissan Bluebird' 
                },
                h: 'Volkswagen',
                i: 'Bugatti',
                j:[ 
                    '% mileage',
                    '% top speed',
                    '% suspension',
                    '% navigation',
                    '% horsepower',
                    '% 0-60s' 
                ] 
            }
var result = Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
   key = key.toUpperCase();
   if (typeof value === 'object') {
     result.push(`${key}:`);
     if (Array.isArray(value)) {
       value.forEach(item => result.push(item));
     } else {
       Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
         key = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)
         result.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
       })
    } 
  } else {
    result.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
  console.log(result.join("\n"))
  return result.join("\n");
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for helping me out. I tried your code and I'm not getting any output. The template shows my error handler and the terminal only shows A: Tesla.

Comment: The `join()` shouldn't be called inside `reduce()`. After the function you can do `var finalData = result.join('\n');` like in your original example :)